# Magic Mouse Gesture not working OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos, imac, mouse, gesture

I am using Magic Mouse with my iMac having OS X Mavericks 10.9.

Everything was working fine since today morning, I realized that my Magic Mouse is only responding to scrolling and primary, secondary click. All other gestures of Magic Mouse were not working.

And another issue which I don't know it is related or not is that Google Chrome does not scroll. Restarting Chrome fixes problem for 2-5 minutes but not permanently.

I use all gestures frequently for spaces, zooming, swapping, navigating, etc and I am having very difficulty without these features.

Things I have tried:

1. Checking/Resetting Magic Mouse settings from system preferences
2. Turn Magic Mouse on and off
3. Disconnect/Connect Magic Mouse
4. Restart iMac, press power button and "command+shift+p+r" and from troubleshoot screen, verify/repair Disk Utility (OS Disk)
5. Connect mouse with other iMac (mouse is fine)

After all these things, problem still exists. I have searched it in Google and I have found out that many people have received this problem but I couldn't find any solution.

Does anyone here know about this issue and have some solution??

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by going to mouse in preference and unblocking the gesture the second and third gesture leaving only the "Swipe between pages" enabled.

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue and called apple.

Reset your PRAM. Fixed the issue for me. Google for how to reset PRAM.

Comment: What makes for a good answer is when you provide the instructions on how do the procedure you recommended so readers don't have to go look up outside Ask Different.   - It's no longer called PRAM, by the way; it's NVRAM

Answer (score -3):

Disable the gesture and the re enable it again...